# Why is China so hostile to the western world?

Tags: united-states, china, western-world

Through domestic education or propaganda, Chinese government is consistently educating its everyone who listens to the CCP mouthpiece that they should be careful of the western threat.

An example today is the Russia-Ukraine war. This is clearly an invasion from a western standpoint, but on China's official mouthpiece and domestic social media platform, the government and their influencers stands together with Russia and blames the western world, telling its people that if Russia is taken down by the west, China will be the next one.

What is the official reason (publicly stated or inferred from official document) that China distrusts the West? Is it true that China cannot get along well with the West? Then how come Singapore can be good friends with the West?

Comment: I might be oversimplifying, but this probably has something to do with the fact that Singapore is a capitalist democracy and China is a(n ostensibly) communist dictatorship.

Comment: The question should make clear, that it´s only about political part. There is no problem in economical part between China and the West.

Comment: Sanctions against Huawei is an economical problem between China and the West

Comment: @avocado : Who said China or CCP is afraid of the West? What quotes or facts do you have to substantiate your claim? And even if China is indeed afraid, whatever it could mean, then what kind of answer do you want? Do you want us to take a wild guess as to what is inside the minds of Chinese policy makers? The whole question looks like an opinion and seems to seek opinion-based answers.

Comment: @F1Krazy Singapore is a “democracy”

Comment: I would give you a counter question instead: What has the West done to China and Chinese people for the last 200 years that would make China wants to be friends with them?

Comment: @FaitoDayo: "designed in California, manufactured in China"? China thus being the [greatest beneficiary of globalization](https://www.brookings.edu/research/chinas-influence-on-the-global-middle-class/), socially at least? The West may be waking up that "change through trade" may have been [a mistake](https://www.dw.com/en/war-in-ukraine-german-foreign-policy-under-fire/a-61436299) though, at least with respect to Russia. And given where Xi is taking China, probably the corollary might not be far behind.

Comment: @FaitoDayo This is not relevant as China is not the country from 200 years ago (Qing Dynasty). If anyone should have a problem with the West on this reasoning, it should be the successors of the dynasty, which is the exiled government of Taiwan. The West backed the monarchy in the civil war because it was not communist. Not only that, but the Qing were generally antagonistic in general: when Europeans wanted to make trade agreements with them, they were rejected on the basis of "a treaty implies equality in status" (and all others were beneath the Middle Kingdom).

Comment: @uberhaxed Chinese think things differently compare to the west. First of all, the current regime thought of themselves (and propaganda as such) that it is the successor to the Republic of China. Also, you are reiterating anti-Chinese propaganda, it is Qing not wanting to trade because they think they have everything, while the West want Chinese gold and sliver--just like in the American continent. And when Qing says no to the traders, they brought out opiums, and when that failed, they brought out the guns and force Chinese onto their knees.

Comment: @Fizz Because China is ran by the CCP, they dont get to "benefit" from anyone else's decision. It has always been planned, since Deng XiaoPing, that China uses its own advantage--population, cheap labor, and resource--to rise to the top. It is not that difference comparing to South Korea's "miracles on the Han River" Do not ever think non-Western nations as sxxthole and full of morons. The only reason South Korea change to democracy is because South's Leader relented to civilian pressure. Just to remind you, US support the side that shoot students during Gwangju Uprising.

Comment: @FaitoDayo Propaganda need not be false. I'm reiterating what you can find in American text books. War is a form of diplomacy and from my perspective, the Europeans have been trying peacefully for decades before resorting to war. The Americans on the other hand did not have that kind of patience for the Japanese and that was certainly not what happened with China. Even in the modern world, you only have the luxury of closed borders if you have the might to back it up. To believe the party based (theoretically democratic) system in modern China is the continuation of the monarchy is absurd.

Comment: The question is based on a false premise. China in happily in business with the Western countries. Did you have a look at the amounts of the international trade with China? Did you have a look at how much they are investing in the belt and road initiative to reach the Western world? The domestic propaganda is just for internal purpose, the ruling party which hardly can be called communist desperately needs an enemy to stay in power.

Comment: Soviet and USA are also very hostile to each other, yet they still do business with each other...it is not a false premise at all.

Answer (score 11):

As an ordinary Chinese who was born, grew up, educated, and worked in China, I think the one who is so afraid of the western world is the CCP instead of China.

Especially since Xi came into power, China is becoming more and more like North Korea: a 100% dictatorship and autocratic state. The real voice of ordinary Chinese people can hardly be heard by foreign countries.

So, why is the CCP so afraid of the western world, and why is the Chinese government supporting Russia in the war?

1. The CCP is afraid of democracy. They are afraid of the culture, the [movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_censorship_in_China) (such as *[A Taxi Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Taxi_Driver#Reactions_in_China)* and *[V for Vendetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta_(film))*), and anything that may inspire the idea of democracy for Chinese people. Almost all of them come from the western world. Also, the CCP built a notorious [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) to prevent Chinese people from using Google, Twitter, YouTube, and any other websites the CCP can't control.
2. Since the PRC was founded, Russia has always been the greatest supporter of the CCP, whether as the Soviet Union or as the current Russian Federation , from money to military technology.

Comment: China and Russia fought a few proxy wars, do you know it?

Comment: Is the Chinese government supporting Russia in the Russo-Ukrainian War? They have certainly criticised the USA and NATO, but they have also said that the territorial integrity of Ukraine should be respected and complied with (some) sanctions on Russia. Like many countries, they appear reluctant to "pick a side".

Comment: @alamar In 1969 they fought a "direct" war, not just a proxy one. Nevertheless I think there is some sense in which the Soviet Union was the CCP's "greatest" supporter, since "greatest" is poorly defined and so subject to many different interpretations.

Comment: @CharlieEvans Yes, you are certainly right. In International Contexts, CCP expresses neutrality on the Russia-Ukraine War. But in the domestic publicity, pro-Ukrainian voices are banned, russian soldiers are portrayed as liberators.

Comment: @alamar Yes, not only proxy wars, but also direct wars like [珍宝岛事件](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8F%8D%E5%AE%9D%E5%B2%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6), it was the result of Mao's battle with the Soviet Union for the top spot in the communist camp. And in an earlier period, China (Qing Dynasty) fought many wars with Tsarist Russia, the Republic of China was forced to recognize Mongolia's independence because of the Soviet Union. Russia is the country that hurt China the most in modern Chinese history, which is even more than the damage caused by Japan in World War II.

Comment: Well, the USA will eventually have China recognize the Tibet's independence if you fail to stop fooling around. At least Russia does not have any standing claims on the Chinese territory.

Comment: Many people have suggested that China (the CCP) wants the Ukraine invasion to be okay because it wants to invade Taiwan in a similar way and wants that to be okay too.

Answer (score 3):

USA is openly declaring China as one of its main adversaries. Perhaps China is aware of the principle "when somebody promises to kill you, do not hesitate to believe them".

China also considers Taiwan as part of itself which may be resolved with an invasion in the future, so there is a point of not being invasion-averse in their news coverage.

Finally, I'm pretty sure that Western countries stood together with the USA much more firmly when it invaded Middle East than the current Chinese benevolent neutrality to Russian actions. Relations matter.

Even Russia supported the USA's Afghanistan campaign by providing airport capacity for NATO supply missions.

Comment: Taiwan is different from Russia & Ukraine war, since it's indeed part of China and became an issue because of the civil war in China many years.

Comment: Modern Taiwan has a strong regional identity. Ukraine was indeed a part of Russian Empire, especially if we are talking about the contested regions.

Comment: @avocado And Ukraine is part of Russia. Or is it? In one year it was part of Russia, and in the next year, it was not.

Comment: @alamar some parts of Ukraine are controversial, but I don't think the big part of Ukraine was part of Russia in the last 100 years, correct? Say Putin can say the east part belonged to Russia, but cannot say the whole country belonged to Russia.  Furthermore, there are different agreements achieved since 2014, Russia acknowledged the east part belongs to Ukraine, but now they regreted and waged a war, I don't think this is a decent move of Russia.

Comment: All of the Ukraine and Russia were a part of the same state (the USSR) as recently as 32 years ago. For Taiwan it's more like 72 years ago that they were in the same de facto state with mainland China - probably more if you discount civil war. Not many people in Taiwan have memories of being a part of China.

Answer (score 3):

China, despite sometimes being allies with the United States, has had a rough history with the West that even predates the current Communist party. While in United States helped support China against Japan during [World War II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-American_sentiment_in_mainland_China), the aid was given to nationalist party (usually through Nationalist politician Chiang Kai-shek) with the idea that they could share it with the Communist party as the Nationalists saw fit. This decision was not liked by the Communist Party and when the Sino-American Mutual Defense Treaty was established from 1955 to 1979, the United States did not recognize the Communist Party of China as China's rightful government. There was also a larger incident in [1993](https://www.nytimes.com/1993/09/06/world/no-chemical-arms-aboard-china-ship.html) where the United States government detained a Chinese ship in international water claiming it might contain chemical weapons intended for Iran, a moment that became known as the Yinhe incident. This history of hostility towards the CCP, in addition to what the other contributors have mentioned, have made the Communist Party and the people who live under their rule to be taught to be very distrustful of the West.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

- Racial unrest in the US.
- Mass shootings.
- Crime rate.
- Negative news coverage of minor events in China.
- The great recession of 2007-2009 crushing Western economies while China's grew substantially.

Add that up and it becomes conceivable that China legitimately thinks they are better than the West. And then there is:

- The West gives off the general feeling that their particular way of thinking is "good" and no free person disagree with them. Furthermore, they view it as their sacred responsibility to go and regime change these other countries even if their population don't want the intervention, because those same people will be happy once they've been enlightened. That's why there is the Iraq War (and Libya). We can see how those wars turned out for the Iraqi/Libyan people too.
- Covid pandemic. China did spectacularly well with managing the pandemic, but most of the Western coverage of China's Covid response has negative undertones (of the "look how repressive their government is" kind). Meanwhile China looks at the rest of the world and thinks "if only everyone else did what we did, the pandemic would have ended in 2020".
- [US funding Hong Kong protesters](https://popularresistance.org/us-exposed-for-funding-last-years-hong-kong-protests/) after complaining about Russian interference in their elections.

You could realistically flip the question around and ask why the West is so afraid of China.

As for Singapore, the country is usually non-aligned. Their participation in sanctions on Russia is unusual in that sense, and was explained as how if invading smaller countries were commonplace things would be dangerous for small countries like Singapore. Non-alignment means they can maintain friendly relations with most countries. But [check this out](https://www.smh.com.au/national/hostile-welcome-for-lee-kuan-yew-20070328-gdps9w.html) anyway. More news coverage emphasizing human rights issues in Singapore can easily flip public opinion (on both sides) around.

Comment: I'm sure re-education camps for blacks would sort out unrest nicely, Xinjiang style.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense. China is afraid of the West because they think they’re better than the West? Based on this argument, they should just relax and sit back, confident that the west will weaken on its own leaving plenty of space for China’s rise. Maybe this is a frame-shift answer, then? If so, you should say that.

Comment: [David Bowie - I'm Afraid of Americans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LT3cERVRoQo)

Answer (score 1):

> Through domestic education or propaganda, China is consistently educating its people or children that they should be careful of the western threat.

They have their own ideological path which needs to be propagated to their citizens. What is strange in that?

> An example today is the Russia-Ukraine war. This is clearly an invasion from a western standpoint, but on China's domestic social media platform, the government seemingly stands together with Russia and blames the western world, telling its people that if Russia is taken down by the west, China will be the next one.

Because (1) the 1989 Tiananmen Square incident; (2) Russia is an ally of China.

> Is it true that China cannot get along well with the West?

No, it is not true. China has good trade relations with the West. Even several Western countries have become part of China's BRI project, e.g., Itay, Greece, etc.

> Then how come Singapore can be good friends with the West?

Singapore is not a one-party state.

Comment: **They have their own ideological path which needs to be propagated to their citizens. What is strange in that?** This is surely strange, I do understand ideological stuff in different countries, but let's say your neighbor constantly tell their children that you are an a**hole. Yes you cannot stop your neighbor from doing that, that's domestic things, but now from a 3rd party perspective, I'm asking why your neighbor would tell that to their children. See, it's not about strange or not, it's about understanding why they do it.

Comment: @avocado, You asked me an invalid question.  If two groups of people have two different and opposing ideologies, they both will consider each other as a**holes. In the case of ideologies, there is no right or wrong. Right or wrong depends on muscle power and propaganda machinery.

Comment: I see, now I got your point, it looks to me that ideologies are like religions, and different religions may conflict others, and there is no right or wrong there. Thanks